# How can I add an user at start in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to create a user if I start my connection to localhost and mongoDB but I don´t know how to do it I tried so many things but don´t know how to get an user at start.

so my Schema looks this way:

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userID: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    isAdministrator: {
        required: Boolean
    }
});
```

And my connection is this:

```
const dbURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
mongoose.connect(dbURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on("error", (err)=>{console.error(err)});
db.once("open", () => { console.log ("Database started successfully")})
```

Comment: Have you completed establishing your database connection?

Comment: Yes it works. I can create a user. I have already a Router function for this but I want that the server is creating an default admin user.

Comment: Do you want when you create the user to get only the normal user rights?

Comment: No, hmm I think I can´t explain myself so good. I try again. So if I hite for example npm start in my terminal I want that the server creates an admin user if not exists. I hope you understand now a little bit

Comment: Ok, Deezer you want to create and user if the user does not exist in the database and you want to display the created user successfully in the terminal if the created user.

Answer (score 1):

Use this user schema if you want to create a normal user-defined by `default: false` and if you want to create admin defined by `default: true`.

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userID: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  userName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  isAdministrator: {
    required: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});
```

Comment: First thanks for that.